# why is my question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I wrote a question before like this "Hi i just installed Ubuntu and it seems like a nice operating system. I just have some questions about the security. How safe is ubuntu? is there no risk developers make source codes like trojans in the operating system , is it safe to download applications and use them? or are there risks that applications can have functions like a trojan?"

It was closed and said to be duplicate question by  *please don't call people out by name in questions...it will only end badly*...
i searched through their questions but did not find any question like my question on them.

Why not give a direct link to that specific question instead?

So for me the question is still like above.

Comment: The link is in the question, right below the title.  But just in case, here it is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1069/why-is-ubuntu-more-secure-than-windows-or-mac-os-x

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out http://askubuntu.com/questions/56850/how-does-application-review-board-work

Comment: Please start by reading the FAQ mathias. http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: more related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1069/why-is-ubuntu-more-secure-than-windows-or-mac-os-x

Answer (score 9):

You appear to be asking multiple questions in one question, the way this site works is to have one question per post (so that you can accept one answer as being the best one). In order for this to work questions need to be posted separately.

I ends up you're asking something things that have been asked before and already have answers for on this site, that's why your question is being closed and redirected to those questions. See the top links on the body of your question:

[image]